# Passing a variable number of arguments to constructors

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to accomplish the following:

```
Entity e;
e.AddComponent<CPosition>(128, 128); //method should instantiate a new CPosition(128,128)
e.AddComponent<CSprite>(some, other, args); //etc
```

The important part is the AddComponent method. It should attempt to construct the generic type with the arguments passed. I believe C++11's variadic templates to forward the arguments to the constructor. However, I do not have access to this functionality yet (VS2010).

Does anyone have any idea on how to do this?

Comment: If you can't use variadic templates, there's always plain old non-type safe variadic functions and passing the list from within that.

Comment: I am actually trying to do something similar, merging Direct3D textures and surfaces into one class for an engine I am writing.  Since I want an answer too, that's a vote up for you, sir.

Comment: You can always specialize the template function, if you only expect to use a small number of template types.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write a bunch of overloads, each taking a different number of parameters.

```
class Entity
{
public:
 template<typename T>
 void AddComponent() { component_ = new T(); }

 template<typename T, typename T1>
 void AddComponent(T1 t1) { component_ = new T(t1); }

 template<typename T, typename T1, typename T2>
 void AddComponent(T1 t1, T2 t2) { component_ = new T(t1, t2); }

 // etc
 ...
};
```

Comment: You should use `&&` and template argument deduction, so that you can forward the parameters correctly.

Comment: The OP says that they're using VS2010, which does not support C++11. (After all, if it did, then they could've just used variadic templates in the first place.)

Comment: It doesn't support variadic templates, but it does support R-value references enough to use perfect forwarding. Just without the variadic part.

Comment: @NicolBolas Any idea how I would go about doing this? Would it be something along the lines of `void AddComponent(T1&& t1, T2&& t2) { component_ = new T(std::forward<T1>(t1), std::forward<T2>(t2);}`? Of course, I will have to create N overloads of this function with argument counts up to N (which I have no issue with doing).

Comment: I realized this is an old thread...and I'm new to C++.  Would a constructor that takes an array or vector be a valid solution in this case?

Comment: @egregious But `e.AddComponent<CPosition>(128, 128);` is not passing an array or a vector, so that doesn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Check how boost::container::vector::emplace_back is implemented:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/container/vector.hpp

It uses Boost.Preprocessor for auto-generation of functions taking different number of arguments. It generates some predefined number of functions.

As the result, you don't have to write each overload by hands. Instead, you can write your pattern only once.

For instance:

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/iteration/local.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/repetition/enum_trailing_params.hpp>

struct Entity
{
#define ENTITY_PP_PARAM_LIST(z, n, data) const BOOST_PP_CAT(P, n) & BOOST_PP_CAT(p, n)
#define ENTITY_PP_PARAM_PASS(z, n, data) BOOST_PP_CAT(p, n)

#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_MACRO(n) \
    template<typename GenericType BOOST_PP_ENUM_TRAILING_PARAMS(n, typename P) > \
    void AddComponent(BOOST_PP_ENUM(n, ENTITY_PP_PARAM_LIST, _)) \
    { \
        something=new GenericType(BOOST_PP_ENUM(n, ENTITY_PP_PARAM_PASS, _)); \
    } \
    /**/

#define BOOST_PP_LOCAL_LIMITS (0, 3)
#include BOOST_PP_LOCAL_ITERATE()
};
```

After preprocessing expands to:

```
struct Entity
{
    template<typename GenericType  >
    void AddComponent()
    {
        something=new GenericType();
    }

    template<typename GenericType , typename P0 >
    void AddComponent( const P0 & p0)
    {
        something=new GenericType( p0);
    }

    template<typename GenericType , typename P0 , typename P1 >
    void AddComponent( const P0 & p0 , const P1 & p1)
    {
        something=new GenericType( p0 , p1);
    }

    template<typename GenericType , typename P0 , typename P1 , typename P2 >
    void AddComponent( const P0 & p0 , const P1 & p1 , const P2 & p2)
    {
        something=new GenericType( p0 , p1 , p2);
    }
};
```

Comment: This looks like an excellent usage of the Boost PP library. In conjunction with Raymond Chen's response, it looks like I have my answer.